# Wait for user permission to continue

Tags: java, android

I want to have my app waited for the user to give the permission before the app continues. I searched other threads about it and found out that the common way would be to use `onRequestPermissionResult`. Now I‘m pretty clueless how to set it up: do I just put my program code into the `onRequestPermissionResult` except the request itself or how do I need to set it up, so the user is asked for it and the app continues afterwards?

This is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
           != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);
   } else {
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       GPSTracker gt = new GPSTracker(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
       Location location = gt.getLocation();

       if (location == null) {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No location found.",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } else {
           lat = location.getLatitude();
           lon = location.getLongitude();
       }
       new GetContacts().execute();
   }
} else {
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  GPSTracker gt = new GPSTracker(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  Location location = gt.getLocation();

  if (location == null) {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No location found.",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else {
      lat = location.getLatitude();
      lon = location.getLongitude();
  }
    new GetContacts().execute();
}
```

And the RequestResult:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 123: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                GPSTracker gt = new GPSTracker(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                Location location = gt.getLocation();

                if (location == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No location found.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    lon = location.getLongitude();
                }
                new GetContacts().execute();

            } else {
                //Toast
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: restructure that, so that the `GPSTracker gt ...` will reside within it's own method, which can be called from both other locations; also consider that `< API 23` there is no support for requesting permissions at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Martin Zeitler mentioned in the comments, you have to prepare for both APIs above and below Marshmallow such as this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
     != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);
    } else {

        //GPS method
    }
} else {

    //GPS method
}
```

and exactly like you mentioned in your question in onRequestResult:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 123: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                //GPS method
            } else {
                // Toast for user
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, how has it been solved back then with api < 23 then if you know that?

Comment: The permissions were added to the manifest and when the user downloaded the app, he/she would be asked for all permissions the app uses to install the app. So no permission during run time. All the above permissions must be declared in your manifest.

Comment: And I guess to do it like that is impossible for newer versions so that is is necessary to check them on runtime?

Comment: Yes exactly, anything that requires a permissions needs to be checked and asked for at run time

Comment: Okay, I edited my code and tried it like this. It seems to work that it waits for the permission, but after it is allowed it does not do anything only my progressbar pops up but never disappears (in the GetContacts it is turned off again). It just works when the app is restarted so there is no asking for the permission again. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: Is this a fragment?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that it's a Fragment, if you're requesting from a fragment you should call: `requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);` without ActivityCompat

Comment: Okay I didn’t know it would make a difference here. Removing the head causes an error that says „requestPermissionw() in Fragment cannot be applied to:“ expected parameters and actual parameters

Comment: did you remove the getActivity() from the arguments?

Comment: By the way did you mean to turn your progress off in the onRequestResult method?

Comment: No I mean a progressbar is turned on in the gos method and turned off in the method that shall run afterwards. And the way it was it only showed the progressbar and nothing more happened. I will try your suggestion, but why is the ActivityCompat and the getActivity() not necessary here?

Comment: Because you’re implementing the Fragnent’s onRequestPermissionsResult, therefore you need to use the Fragment’s requestPermission() method

Comment: Perfect. Everything works just as it should, thank you very much, you‘ve been a big help for me!

Comment: Don’t mention it :). Happy coding and pass the knowledge forward :)

Comment: I definitely will! :)